# Difference between having targetnamespace attribute value as dot vs slashes in .xsd file?

Tags: xml, spring, xsd

Can someone tell me the difference between defining targetnamespace as below in relation to spring-ws

```
http://checkingaccountservice.example.zoo 

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="http://checkingaccountservice.example.zoo"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
    ...
<xsd:schema>
```

### vs

```
http://zoo/example/checkingaccountservice/

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="http://zoo/example/checkingaccountservice"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
    ...
<xsd:schema>
```

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be blunt, there is no difference.

An XML namespace URI is to be considered as an opaque string. It's just a unique string to prevent collisions. Whether you use '.' or '/' characters in that string is a choice, as long as you can guarantee that the string will be unique.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I would add to that that it's advisable, though not absolutely essential, to ensure that namespace names are legal absolute URIs. Some software will reject them if they aren't, though most will just accept them as written. It's also good manners to use a URI whose domain name part is a domain that you own or control.